# Prevention against accidentally referencing a view (by ID) in another activity's fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view, findviewbyid

Is there a way to type-safe or check at compile time when I try to to a findViewById(R.id.activity_2_text_view) in the onCreate() of activity1? I keep running into null pointer runtime errors - so was wondering if there was any compile time checks possible

Thanks

Comment: Why would you try to access a view in a layout from a different activity?

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no such compile-time checks that I'm aware of.

In theory a static analyzer like Android Lint could have rules in it to check where an identifier is introduced and where it is used. Such rules have not been implemented yet. ([ref](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks))

The runtime exceptions you get from using a wrong id are deterministic and easy to debug. That's probably the best mechanism for such problems.

As always, the problem with your code is that it is doing exactly what you're telling it to do.